# kafka-go delay time in writing an event

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I'm using [kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go) and I'm seeing that each event adding by itself takes one second.
I played around with the configs, and I see it's because kafka waits to batch my events to 100 or it has a timeout of one second. That means it waits until it gets to a batch of 100 events or after one second it sends what it has in the batch.

My question is how do I lower the timeout time? instead of one second, I would like 100ms.

and I have this configuration for the writer:

```
writer := kafka.Writer{
        //BatchSize: 100,
        Addr:     kafka.TCP(kafkaURL),
        Topic:    topic,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

found the solution, you need to use: `BatchTimeout`

I tried it by setting it to 0, but it didn't work just because of the function below. to make it work you need to set a low value (depends on what you need)
`BatchTimeout: time.Millisecond * 10,`

```
func (w *Writer) batchTimeout() time.Duration {
    if w.BatchTimeout > 0 {
        return w.BatchTimeout
    }
    return 1 * time.Second
}
```